# Publisher policy registry entries not cleaned up after an uninstall

Tags: wix, windows-installer, merge-module

**Scenario:**
I have a merge module which contains certain assemblies, which get installed into the GAC. 
This merge module is consumed by a msi package.

The merge module also contains  GAC publisher policy files associated with each of the assemblies.

When the msi package is installed , several registry entries corresponding to these publisher policy files are created under:HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Fusion\PublisherPolicy\Default. After an uninstall of this msi package, even though the actual publisher policy files and the assemblies are cleaned up from the GAC, the registry entries corresponding to the publisher policy files are not cleaned up.

**Investigation carried out so far:**

To summarize, the URL below states that the Windows Installer standard for including Publisher Policy Files within an installer is to add them directly to the MSI package and not a Merge Module.   The problem with adding them to the Merge Module causes the associated Policy registry keys utilized by the CLR to be orphaned in the registry.

I believe the link below describes the cause of this issue and basically Windows Installer Standards indicate that Merge Modules should not be used to install Publisher Policy Files into the GAC.  Perhaps the intention with installer validation is to force the Policy files to have explicit association to a specific Product Version.

Reference: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa369203(v=vs.85).aspx

In order to verify the behavior I manually modified the msi install package and removed the Policy file components from the ModuleComponents Table.  By doing so removes the component reference from being associated to the merge module and directly assigns them to the MSI package. 
After uninstalling, the Policy file registry entries are no longer orphaned in the registry and the problem is solved

**Potential solution**

The long term solution would be to redesign the Merge Modules to exclude the Policy files and add them directly to each Product MSI Package

***Does anyone have any other better solution to fix this problem?***

Regards, 
Kiran Hegde